# What should CodeIgniter default controller be when implementing RESTful service?

Tags: php, codeigniter, rest

I am using the CodeIgniter REST Server Library

https://github.com/philsturgeon/codeigniter-restserver

One problem about CodeIgniter is that it is not a RESTful framework. I get confused about the routes.php file that I have to set a "default controller."

```
$route['default_controller'] = "welcome";
```

What should I choose to be the default_controller if the server is fully RESTful?

Comment: its just the name that you want to use to reach your rest server. so if you want an address of: http://domain.com/wind You would create a controller called wind.php and in routes change default from welcome to wind.

Comment: This might be my misunderstanding of the REST server. I thought REST server is completely passive and only takes requests from other sources. If it is passive, the "default controller" should be moot. They must always use domain.com/wind/Articles (GET) to retrieve articles, but domain.com/wind (or just domain.com/) does not make any sense because I don't know what people would want by typing in this.

Comment: Download the REST client: https://github.com/philsturgeon/codeigniter-restclient Read the tutorial: http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/working-with-restful-services-in-codeigniter-2/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add `$route['(:any)'] = "your_default_controller/$1";` in your route config.
but it work for one controller. if you want to call another controller you still need including your controller at your URL `http://localhost/api_rest/your_another_controller/method`.